# Youtube API returns empty items list

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to wrap my head around this. So I am livestreaming to Youtube through OBS (Open Broadcast[er] Software) and it's working just fine. Now I tried to create an interface to check the status of the stream towards youtube to keep me updated.

I did get the API call working, but it is always returning me an empty dataset where the stream information is supposed to be. So I'm making a `GET` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts` endpoint, and this is the response that I get:

```
{
   "kind": "youtube#liveStreamListResponse",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/5kFXSBljnknEhZeBh_drVCsPVKo\"",
   "pageInfo": {
       "totalResults": 0,
       "resultsPerPage": 5
   },
   "items": []
}
```

So the problem is that items is not supposed to be empty. It is supposed to give me information regarding the stream and its state. I'm passing my Youtube channel id in as a parameter, and also a required parameter `part` with the value `status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might be wondering later, you will not find your own broadcast from the liveBroadcasts endpoint unless you set the `broadcastType` variable to `persistent` in the request.